# CAS4 Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat7, cas

I'm deploying **Jasig CAS 4.0.0** using [Maven Overlay Installation](https://github.com/UniconLabs/simple-cas4-overlay-template).
I created my custom classes and when deploying it I get this error in the cas.log:

`Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class ...)`

#### Environment specs

- OS: Debian 7
- Web server: Apache tomcat 7.0.28
- Java: Oracle 8,

  - Java & Javac version: 1.8.0_40,
  - Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre,
- Maven:v 3.0.4,
- Eclipse Luna,

#### Maven POM

- maven-compiler-plugin: 3.2
- maven.compiler.source: 1.8
- maven.compiler.target: 1.8

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your runtime must not be using Java 8 (even if you believe it does). Dbl check the one used by tomcat: if you have tomcat manager installed you can use its web page to check it, if not add echo to catalin.sh to check java version used. 
Typically in linux you jave more than one Java SDK installed, with java being a link to the most recent one. But tomcat can have its own path to JavaSDK set using JAVA_HOME.

Comment: Thanks, this saves my day. The tomcat was using default 1.6 java.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue too. For those looking for detailed instructions: 1) Go to File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle 2) Set "Gradle JVM" to point to the 1.8 JDK